Why does Beanfactory not getting initialized after updating to 3.2.3?
I'm trying to update from spring boot 3.1.7 to 3.2.3, but running into issues where the app does not start.
The app works fine with spring-boot 3.1.7 and see the following log statements on startup including the text in bold.
main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-secret/dev/my-service'}]
main] c.lexmark.mse.AgentServiceApplication    : The following 2 profiles are active: "mse", "prod"
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 497 ms. Found 49 JPA repository interfaces.
**main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=7f4f6f66-b447-3316-a4b7-f9c57a303f4c**
main] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.lexmark.mse.core.messaging.event.aspect.EventAspect

Whereas with spring-boot 3.2.3, I do not see the 'Beanfactory id=' line as above and suspect the bean factory is not getting initialized for some reason. NOTE: I've also set the -parameters option in Javacompile
main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-secret/dev/my-service'}]
main] c.lexmark.mse.AgentServiceApplication    : The following 2 profiles are active: "mse", "prod"
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 497 ms. Found 49 JPA repository interfaces.

There are no exceptions/errors in the logs either. Any idea what could be causing this behavior?
I've looked over the lib versions and not sure what am I missing, appreciate any help.
Update: The app starts up fine when run with gradlew bootRun but see the below issue when running the jar file.
